# App page tab geting 404 on good url

Tags: facebook-apps, facebook-page

I created an app (id:155124624522900 - https://developers.facebook.com/apps/155124624522900)

And it is supposed to work as page server for Business Pages (as a tab)

But I get this code when trying to access from my debug app:

> App Temporarily Unavailable The URL
>   The URL http://foodtreedevfb.herokuapp.com/tab returned a 404 Not Found error.

Still, the url is good! I wonder what is happening.

I am serving from Play Framework on Heroku.

**EDIT**
it may be related to some trailing slash issue on the uri, still I changed and it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your app redirecting when Facebook sends the POST request? this can happen if your URLs in Facebook's settings are setup without the trailing '/'

Also, check your index file allows POST requests - i'm not sure if heroku have any such restrictions but many other servers won't allow POST requests to some URLs

Comment: What I was about to write.. I added POST routes and it worked, thanks

Comment: Just to complement, I wish it was better explained about POST and trailing '/' in the page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/ 
And also, Heroku is just the host, they accept all verbs in all routes, if any restriction is present is due the web library or framework of choice.